# Forcing lightbox/dhtml over flash

Tags: css, flash, dhtml, lightbox

I have read a lot of posts about how you can force lightbox (or other dhtml things) above flash by modifying the embed-tag with wmode="opaque". Just modifying the z-index of lightbox (or whatever else you want above the flash) simply is not enough.

But what if you cannot control the embed-tag?

I am working with a client that has a banner-system, where I do not have control of the embed tag...

Is there really nothing I can do to force the html over the flash-item, that does not require manipulating the embedding of the flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best chance would probably be having your own embed/iframe element and have it be a sibling of the embed element and give it a higher stacking order with a position and index, you could also try making it a direct child of the body element so it has a higher z-index than the embed element's parent element.